# Having trouble with terminating code on a recessive palindrome method

Tags: java, palindrome, stack-overflow

I'm trying to write code that tells the user if a word they input is a palindrome or not.

I am using a recursive method to reverse the word, but it isn't terminating correctly. The `StackOverFlowError` appears when I test it out.  My terminating code looks correct to me, so I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Also, when I try to make the `String` object all lower case characters, does the debugger show that the word was made all lower case, or does it just stay the same?

**Here is the code:**

```
public class Palindrome
{
private String word;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class PalindromeTester
 */
public Palindrome(String supposedPalindrome)
{
    word = supposedPalindrome;
}

/**
 * Tests if the word is a palindrome or not.
 */
public void testPalindrome()
{
    String reversed = reverse();
    if(reversed.equals(word.toLowerCase()))
    {
        System.out.println(word + " is a palindrome!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(word + " is not a palindrome.");
    }    
}

/**
 * Reverses the word.
 * 
 * @return the reversed string.
 */
private String reverse()
{
    return reverseHelper(word);
}

/**
 * A recursive method that reverses the String for the
 * reverse the string method.
 * 
 * @return the reversed string.
 */
private String reverseHelper(String s)
{
    s.toLowerCase();
    if(s.length() <= 1)
    {
        return s;
    }
    else
    {
        return reverseHelper(s.substring(1, s.length()) + s.charAt(0));
    }
}
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two mistakes in your code:

1. String are **immutable**
   so doing `s.toLowerCase()` won't make any changes to `s`, you need to assign in back to an `String`
   `s = s.toLowerCase();`
2. Your recursive method is buggy
   `return reverseHelper(s.substring(1, s.length()) + s.charAt(0));`
   it always passes `String` of length `s.length()` *(I mean if `String s` is of length **5** then you recursive call is always passing string of length 5 only with only position of characters being changed)*

**Suggestion:**

1. make you recursive call to shorten you string each time so that it finally matches `if` condition after string has been reversed
2. Or use [StringBuilder#reverse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29) method to reverse your string

Comment: Oh, ok, that makes a lot more sense to me now realizing that the length wont change after each call.  Thank you!

Comment: It turns out I had the parenthesis in the wrong spots on the return helper.  I just had to take the s.charAt(0) our of the reverseHelper parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a recursive system when there's a built-in way?

```
public class Palindrome() {
  public Palindrome(String supposedPalindrome) {
    if( supposedPalindrome.equals(new StringBuffer(supposedPalindrome).reverse().toString())) {
      System.out.println(supposedPalindrome+" is a palindrome!");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println(supposedPalindrome+" is not a palindrome!");
    }
  }
}
```

Or something like that, using [`StringBuffer`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)'s built-in `reverse()` method.

Comment: May be OP is trying his hands on implementing reverse method of his own

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable. String.toLowerCase(String) returns a new String.

Replace

```
s.toLowerCase();
```

with

```
s = s.toLowerCase();
```

or even better

```
return reverseHelper(word.toLowerCase());
```

and remove

```
s.toLowerCase();
```